# How to remove nodes after a particular text using jsoup?

Tags: email, jsoup

I am parsing email replies and want to extract the "reply" and leave the quoted part out. Have been pretty successfull so far. I notice that Android email clients have this sort of HTML:

```
    ....
    <div>
      <div style="font-size:100%">Sent via the Samsung Galaxy Tab® 3</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    -------- Original message --------<br>
    From: Joe Cool <joe.cool@xxxxxxx.com><br>
    Date:04/16/2014 10:06 PM (GMT-08:00) <br>
    <div> ....
```

What I want to do is remove all latter siblings of the "--- Original Message ----" text node. How do I do this?

Comment: Rather than removing things that you don't want, consider only grabbing things that you do want.

Comment: You may go to try.jsoup.org, paste your code there and test various css queries until you extract what you want. If you don't succeed, paste a sample html code in your question and highlight what you want to extract.